# Set start route in ASP.NET MVC visual studio development server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2008, asp.net-mvc-routing

My route is configured to require a certain extension.

Because of this I get an `HttpException` when I try to debug from visual studio: `The incoming request does not match any route.`

I then have to manualy append the `{controller}.{extension}` section to the localhost URL in the address bar.

I've tried playing around with the project settings but haven't managed to get it working.

So, to clarify, I would like my project to go directly to

`http://localhost:1440/mycontroller.ext`

when I run it under visual studio on local machine.

Comment: Can I confirm that you've got this working under IIS already? Otherwise any work around found is potentially going to bite you later on?

Comment: Yes it runs fine on the live server, it was just a pain not having one click start on my local machine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you talking about setting the default URL for when you hit F5 in Visual Studio? If so this should do the trick:

1. Right click on your web project and select Properties.
2. On the Web tab, under Start Action, select Specific page
3. Enter `mycontroller.ext` in the textbox

Hit F5.

Comment: Weird, I tried that before and it didn't work for some reason. Must have got something wrong somewhere. Seems all good now though. Thanks